# Create a complete Alexa skill with AWS or ASK CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

Is it possible to create a custom Alexa skill with the back-end Lambda (code) completely from AWS/ASK CLI? The Lambda interacts with DynamoDB, so it would be ideal to include the provisioning of the DynamoDB backend via the CLI too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it with DynamoDB provisioning (otherwise, yes, please check [this page](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html#create-new-skill)).
Here's a [feature request](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/33756796-add-dynamodb-to-ask-cli) for supporting DynamoDB provisioning in the CLI (please vote up!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very much possible. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html#create-new-skill). If you use Visual Studio Code then there is an extension that integrates ask cli with it.